# SOAP, Help getting started with methods and Connection

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, soap, arraylist

I am trying to make my first SOAP webservice, my first method **getAll()** is supposed to return an arrayList with all farmacy objects. I need help to start because of my limited JAVA knowledge,

I have:

- mySQL DBConnection Class
- Farmacy Class

  *Should i make a FarmacyCollection class with Arraylist and store Farmacies there? 
  Where should i connect to DB for SQL query and then store data?*

And a FarmacyService . java that looks like this:

```
package ApotekService;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "ApotekServSoap")
public class ApotekServSoap {

//How do i connect, retrieve and store mysql objects in farmacy class?
// How to put farmacy in Arraylist?
/**
 * Web service operation
 */
@WebMethod(operationName = "getAll")
public ArrayList getAll() {

    //Return ArrayList with all FarmacyObjects (ArrayList<Apotek>)
    //How do i write this code??
    return null;
}
```

}